# Search Object with it's member and delete it in a list

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have a comboBox which shows the name of an object. The objects are added from a list.

```
     private List<Tool> toolList = new List<Tool>();

     private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        InputDialog input = new InputDialog();
        input.ShowDialog();
        inputNewTool = input.enteredTxt;

        if (inputNewTool != null)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Chose the Tool's directory");
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".exe";
            dlg.Filter = "Application (.exe)|*.exe";

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Tool tool = new Tool();
                tool.Name = inputNewTool;
                tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
                toolList.Add(tool);
                comboBoxTools.Items.Add(tool.Name);
            }                
       }            
     }
```

Now I want with a remove button that not only the object name is deleted from the comboBox. It is necessairy that the object with this name has to be erased from the list.

```
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int position = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBoxTools.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            position = comboBoxTools.SelectedIndex;
            removeTool = comboBoxTools.Items[position].ToString();
        }
        if (position != -1)
        {
            for (int i = toolList.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                if (Condition?)
                {
                    toolList.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            //foreach (Tool t in toolList)
            //{

            //}
            comboBoxTools.Items.RemoveAt(position);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No Item choosed");
        }
    }
```

I don't have a clue how to realize this
Edit: Could it be that comboBox doesn't provide DataSource or DisplayMember? What do I have to include so that I can use them?

Comment: How is declared toolList?

Comment: private List<Tool> toolList = new List<Tool>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use an 
`ObservableCollection<StatisticsItem> Tools;`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

And set :

```
comboBoxTools.ItemsSource = Tools
```

in your constructor.

Your button add is :

```
  private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    InputDialog input = new InputDialog();
    input.ShowDialog();
    inputNewTool = input.enteredTxt;

    if (inputNewTool != null)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Chose the Tool's directory");
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".exe";
        dlg.Filter = "Application (.exe)|*.exe";

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Tool tool = new Tool();
            tool.Name = inputNewTool;
            tool.Path = dlg.FileName;
            toolList.Add(tool);
            Tools.add(tool)
        }                
   }            
 }
```

wich will automatically update your combo box and the delete button :

```
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(combobox.SelectedItem != null)
        Tools.remove((Tool) combobox.SelectedItem);
    else
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No Item choosed");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing items by index, simply remove items by their value:

```
string name = comboBoxTools.SelectedItem;
toolList.RemoveAll(t => t.Name == name);
comboBoxTools.Items.Remove(name);
```

I also suggest you to take a look on usage of [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for tools, and binding this list directly to ComboBox:

```
BindingList<Tool> tools = new BindingList<Tool>();

private void YourForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBoxTools.DisplayMember = "Name"; // set display member
    comboBoxTools.DataSource = tools; // bind tools to comboBox
}

private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ... create tool 

    // that will add tool both to tools list and comboBox
    tools.Add(tool);
}

private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Tool tool = comboBoxTools.SelectedItem as Tool;
    if(tool == null)
       return;

    // that will remove tool both from tools list and comboBox
    tools.Remove(tool);
}
```

Comment: hm what have I  conlude so that i can use DataSource and DisplayMember with the comboBox?

Comment: @LittleProgrammer sorry, didn't get your question. You have some problems with specifying these properties?

Comment: hm visual studio says to me that its doesn't know "DisplayMember" and "DataSource". Have I include some usings?

Comment: @LittleProgrammer no, `DisplayMember` and `DataSource` are properties of [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx) class. What type your `comboBoxTools` variable have?

Comment: ComboBox. I can use only "DisplayMemberPath"

Comment: @LittleProgrammer which combobox? Is it Winfroms or WPF?

Comment: WPF. Maybe it is Data Context and DisplayMemberPath?

Comment: @LittleProgrammer code above is for Winforms - you havent tagget your question with appropriate tag, so Winforms was assumed due to System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox usage. It looks like its better to use ObservableCollection with WPF. Also I don't remember details of data binding in WPF, because last time used it many years ago. I still suggest to stick with data binding. Google for databinging combobox in wpf

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** you are using `RemoveAt()` method to remove the items from the ComboBox.

the problem with `RemoveAt()` method is it will always reshuffle the Itmes Index positions.

**Solution :** you can use `ComboBox.Items.Remove()` method to just Remove the SelectedItem without taking any headache.

Try This: You can use `Remove()` method instead of `RemoveAt()`

```
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   comboBoxTools.Items.Remove(comboBoxTools.SelectedItem);
   toolList.Remove(comboBoxTools.SelectedItem);
}
```

Comment: that isn't my problem to remove this from the comboBox. I want to remove also the object from the list. Only the object member "name" is added to the comboBox. So I want delete the object with this name also from the list when I delete the name in the comboBox

Comment: @LittleProgrammer: check my edited answer, you can use List.Remove() method to remove item from list aswell.